# Problem removing 1 item from a database array SQL

Tags: postgresql, discord.js

So I'm making a use command for discord the Database I use is Postgres SQL I'm having an issue with getting to only remove 1 of the multiple items with the same name

```
await client.db.query(
          `UPDATE inventory SET bag = array_remove(bag, $2) WHERE user_id = $1 AND bag @> ARRAY[$2]
           AND array_position(bag, $2) = (SELECT MIN(array_position(bag, $2)) FROM inventory WHERE user_id = $1 AND bag @> ARRAY[$2]);`,
          [message.author.id, item.name],
        );
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?